# Why doesn't mConnectThread.start() make the program proceed to the ConnectThread class?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm struggling with a bluetooth communication between an Android phone and an Arduino bluetooth module (HC-06). I'm having trouble with the continuity of the code. If I start debugging, there is no problem at all until the program reaches mConnectThread.start(); line. At that point it "stops": stays in debug mode but I'm pressing Step over in vain, does not proceed. Apparently it doesn't jump to ConnectThread class and I don't have a clue why this occurs.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private String MAC = "30:14:10:17:06:93";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView supportsBTorNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.supportsBTorNot);
    TextView listPairedDevices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listPairedDevices);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        supportsBTorNot.setText("The device does not support bluetooth.");
    }
    else{
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
        else{
            supportsBTorNot.setText("The device supports bluetooth.");
        }
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    listPairedDevices.setText(pairedDevices.toString());
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if(device.getAddress().equals(MAC)) {
                mDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mDevice == null) {
        //Device is not paired yet
        //Need to initiate a connection request
    }

    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();
}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    TextView socketConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socketConnected);

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            socketConnected.setText("The socket is established successfully.");
        }
        else {
            socketConnected.setText("The socket could not be stablished.");
        }

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Thread.start()` simply starts that thread, the debugger will not jump to the new thread's context of execution.  You'd have to set a breakpoint in the `run()` method of the thread to step through that.  You are calling `start()` at the end of your `onCreate()` method, which is a framework defined callback.  After you step over the call to `start()` or continue your execution, the `onCreate()` method returns and the debugger will not stop again until another breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.